# Auto suggest textbox client-side - jQuery

Tags: jquery, autosuggest

I want to have a auto suggest textbox where the tags will be present in the array in the javascript, so no request to server.

Comment: That's no really a question. It's more like a statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check out JQuery UI Autocomplete.

This is the link to the demo: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

The first demo 'Default Functionality' addresses your problem

Answer (score 1):

Most autosuggest plugins support this. I use this one and it works great: http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin

Answer (score 0):

I got this

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of values then (if using jQuery) use .inArray. See here: 
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/